# Como validar uma linha digitável de boletos de cobrança no formato 00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000?

Tags: c#, boleto

Boa tarde amigos,

por acaso alguém teria algum procedimento semelhante a [esse](http://pastebin.com/MjLgRB2F) e que poderia postar aqui?

Será de grande utilidade pra mim e pra futuros leitores desse post.

Aguardo retorno.

Aqui foi minha última tentativa de tradução deste código Delphi, mas está errado.

```
private static bool Ok = true;

    public static string RemoveFirst(this string source, string remove)
            {
                int index = source.IndexOf(remove);
                return (index < 0)
                    ? source
                    : source.Remove(index, remove.Length);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Valida o dígito verificador da linha
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="chaveAcesso"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>

    public static string RetornaDigitoVerificadorCteModulo11(string chaveAcesso)
            {

                int peso = 2;
                int soma = 0;

                try
                {
                    chaveAcesso.ToCharArray()
                        .Reverse()
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(f =>
                        {
                            soma += (Convert.ToInt32(f.ToString()) * peso);
                            peso = (peso == 9) ? 2 : peso + 1;
                        });

                    return (11 - (soma % 11)) <= 1 ? "0" : (11 - (soma % 11)).ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return "ERRO: A chave de acesso deve conter apenas números.";
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Valida de forma generalizada o DV da linha digitável
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="linhaDigtavel"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>

            private static bool ValidacaoGeralDV(string linhaDigtavel)
            {
                string Dv;
                string DvVerificado;

                Dv = linhaDigtavel;

                RemoveFirst(Dv, " ");
                RemoveFirst(Dv, " ");
                RemoveFirst(Dv, " ");

                Dv = Dv.Substring(0, Dv.Length);
                DvVerificado = RetornaDigitoVerificadorCteModulo11(linhaDigtavel);

                return (DvVerificado == Dv) ? true : false;

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Validação geral da linha digitável
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="linha"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>

            private static void ValidacaoGeralLinha(string linha)
            {

                char[] caracteresLinha = linha.ToCharArray();


                bool correto =  (caracteresLinha[6] == '.') && 
                                (caracteresLinha[12] == ' ') &&
                                (caracteresLinha[18] == '.') &&
                                (caracteresLinha[25] == ' ') &&
                                (caracteresLinha[31] == '.') &&
                                (caracteresLinha[38] == ' ') &&
                                (caracteresLinha[40] == ' ');

                if (correto)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 54; i++)
                    {
                        if ( (i != 6) &&
                           (i != 12) &&
                           (i != 18) &&
                           (i != 25) &&
                           (i != 31) &&
                           (i != 38) &&
                           (i != 40) )
                        {
                            if (!linha.Contains(i.ToString()))
                            {

                                Ok = false;
                                break;
                            }


                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Retorna a linha digitável já validada no formato: 00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="dado"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>

            private static string RetornaLinhaValidada(string dado)
            {
                string resultado = "";

                for (int i = 1; i <= dado.Length; i++)
                {

                    resultado = dado.Substring(0, dado.Length);


                    ValidacaoGeralLinha(resultado);

                    if (Ok)
                    {
                        if (ValidacaoGeralDV(resultado))

                            break;

                    }

                }

                return "";
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(RetornaLinhaValidada("10490.05539 03698.700006 00091.449587 5 55490000028531"));
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
```

Comment: Cada banco tem um jeito diferente, tem que pedir a documentação deles. Na verdade, acho que não é uma questão de programação propriamente dita.

Comment: Desenvolver isso vai ser o seu menor problema. Como já dito pelo bigown, cada banco tem um padrão diferente. Você precisa ter a documentação do banco para trabalhar nisso.

Comment: Você quer validar somente o formato ou quer validar o código?

Comment: O formato Randrade, assim como no código Delphi.

Comment: Vamos do início @JonasSilva. O que exatamente você precisa fazer? Você quer passar a linha digitável e validar exatamente o que?

Comment: Acho que está biblioteca pode te ajudar:
https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet

Comment: @jbueno, quero validar dígito verificador e formato da linha para o padrão em questão.

Comment: @JonasSilva Se você quer validar o dígito verificador, você precisa de uma implementação para cada banco. Não é possível fazer uma implementação que englobe todos os bancos.

Comment: @jbueno, o famoso Módulo11, já não seria uma validação "global" independentemente de qual banco seja?

Comment: @jbueno, inclusive essa função aí do Módulo 11 em Delphi retorna o dígito corretamente independente do banco :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quer validar somente o formato, aqui está uma solução com Expressão Regular:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        Console.WriteLine(ValidarLinhaDigitavel("00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000"));
    }

    public static bool ValidarLinhaDigitavel(string input)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d{5}\.\d{5} \d{5}\.\d{6} \d{5}\.\d{6} \d \d{14}");
    }
}
```